# Android - (SQLite) Foreign key refer to multiple id at once

Tags: android, sqlite, foreign-keys

i am trying to insert an expense that refer to many friends. But using foreign key, it can only refer to a friendId, but i wan to store 2 friendId instead of one for expenseFriend in expenses table. Because each friend can have many expenses, and a expense can shared by many friends. How can i implement this relationship? Maybe not using foreign key? Can anyone give me idea of doing that? Thanks alot.

This is my create database code:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    String query, query1, query2, query3;
    query = "CREATE TABLE events ( eventId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, eventName TEXT, eventDate TEXT, eventLocation TEXT, eventDescription TEXT);";
    query1 = "CREATE TABLE friends ( friendId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, friendName TEXT, friendNumber TEXT, friendEmail TEXT, friendSpending DOUBLE, friendEvent INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(friendEvent) REFERENCES events(eventId) ON DELETE CASCADE);";
    query2 = "CREATE TABLE expenses ( expenseId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, expenseName TEXT, expenseType TEXT, expensePrice REAL, expenseQuantity INTEGER, expenseEvent INTEGER REFERENCES events(eventId) ON DELETE CASCADE, expenseFriend INTEGER REFERENCES friends(friendId) ON DELETE CASCADE);";
    query3 = "CREATE TABLE temporary (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, spendingId INTEGER)";
    database.execSQL(query);
    database.execSQL(query1);
    database.execSQL(query2);
    database.execSQL(query3);
    Log.d(LOGCAT, "events Created");
    Log.d(LOGCAT, "friends Created");
    Log.d(LOGCAT, "expenses Created");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> each friend can have many expenses, and a expense can shared by many friends

This means that there is a many-to-many relationship between friends and expenses. The rule of thumb states that all many-to-many relationships generate a new table. Having said that, you should create the following tables (in bold the primary keys):

- FRIENDS: **friendId**, friendName...
- EXPENSES: **expenseId**, expenseName...
- FRIENDS_EXPENSES: **friendId**, **expenseId**

Note that in the new table there are 2 bold fields. That doesn't mean that there are 2 primary keys but rather that there is one compound primary key. That is to say, there can be repeated friendId as well as repeated expenseId but the pair (friendId, expenseId) will be unique.

That way you'll turn a many-to-many relationship into 2 one-to-many relationships, which you seem to know how to work with.

Comment: So when i want to access the data, what should i do? select friendId or expenseId?

Comment: It depends on the `data` you want to select :) I'd recommend you to Google about SQL join statements